# UITextView grow inside of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I've seen a lot of questions related to this on SO, however, none of them pertain to my question.

I'm to create an app that has a messaging functionality. Similar to how Apple has Mail and LinkedIn has it's Mail feature in their app, I would like to have a `UITableView` with 3 rows. The third row has the `UITextView` which has to grow as the user types. My code is below:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (bodyText.contentSize.height > currentContentHeight) {
        currentContentHeight = bodyText.contentSize.height;

        [tblView beginUpdates];
        [tblView endUpdates];

        [bodyText setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310.0, currentContentHeight)];

        bodyText.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 0);

    } else {
        currentContentHeight = minimumContentHeight;

        [tblView beginUpdates];
        [tblView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

When I press return on the iPhone it goes down and works flawlessly. Problem is that if I goto the center or any other middle part of the `UITextView`, it seems to create funny behaviour because it's getting the `contentSize` incorrectly. For example:

- I press return 10 times
- Goto the fifth line and type 'dog'
- It gets `contentHeight` based on that 5th line, if that makes sense?

Is there a way to calculate it based on **all** of the text currently? Please let me know if there is anything I have missed above. I read the following extensively:

http://dennisreimann.de/blog/uitextview-height-in-uitableviewcell/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985394/growing-uitextview-and-uitableviewcell

[UITextView inside a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022205/uitextview-inside-a-uitableviewcell)

[How do I size a UITextView to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use UITableView? It seems like a simple 3-view setup (with autolayout) might be easier/better.

Comment: I did it this way because of current design constraints. However, that wouldn't make much difference. Since the `contentHeight` is being calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Also, UITableView makes it easier for scrolling to the proper line etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the code above with the following and it's working for me:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {    
    // Get the number of lines in the current view
    NSUInteger lines = textView.text.length;
    if ((lines * 25) > currentContentHeight && (lines * 25) >= minimumContentHeight && bodyText.contentSize.height > minimumContentHeight) {

        currentContentHeight = bodyText.contentSize.height;

    } else if (lines < 5){
        currentContentHeight = minimumContentHeight;
    }

    [tblView beginUpdates];
    [tblView endUpdates];

    [bodyText setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, currentContentHeight)];

    bodyText.selectedRange = [bodyText selectedRange];
}
```

I set the `currentContentHeight` equal to the `minimumContentHeight` in the beginning based on the size of the phone.